# What i am doing wrong ? (writing dummy activity and call it via c#)

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I read Thread "More Google OBB drama", and saw this : "The OBB is added to the "search path" during a pause/resume cycle of the main activity. Application.dataPath will indicate if it is mounted.
So you need to trigger that a pause/resume cycle if its not mounted (simplest way would be to init a "dummy" activity that only returns immediately" from eriQue. So i try this, but i think that i am doing wrong, cause i am very very noobish with java and android develop (activities). Here are my code:

```
public class ReloadObbActivity extends Activity {

private Intent myIntent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myIntent= new Intent(this,ReloadObbActivity.class);
    finish();
}

public void Launch()
{
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

}

```
 public static void RunDummyActivity()
{
    using (AndroidJavaClass unity_player = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
    {

        var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("mycompany.com.reloadobbplugin.ReloadObbActivity");
        jc.Call("Launch");



        if (AndroidJNI.ExceptionOccurred() != System.IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Exception occurred while attempting to start DownloaderActivity - is the AndroidManifest.xml incorrect?");
            AndroidJNI.ExceptionDescribe();
            AndroidJNI.ExceptionClear();
        }
    }
}
```

So it does not work and no exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know where i were wrong.

```
public class DummyActivity extends Activity
{
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    finish();
  }

  public static void Launch(Activity activity)
  {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, DummyActivity.class);
    activity.startActivity(myIntent);
  }
}
```

And c# code:

```
public static void RunDummyActivity()
        {
            using (AndroidJavaClass unity_player = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                AndroidJavaObject current_activity = unity_player.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

                var jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.exampleCompany.DummyActivity");
                jc.CallStatic("Launch", current_activity);
            }
        }
```

Export java code to jar file and place it in Plugins/Android.
And dont forget to add line with this activity to manifest.